<account-logo> tag helper emits invalid HTML
Using this tag:
<vc:account-logo skin='@(theme.BaseSettings.Layout.DarkMode ? "dark": "light")'></vc:account-logo>

I get this HTML:
<img src="/Common/Images/my-logo-on-light.png&t=638652719991665603" alt="" class="h-40px">

The & makes the URL invalid, and a 404 is shown in the browser console for the logo.
We're using ASPNETZero version 13.2, and it's probably a few months before we can upgrade to the latest.
I've tried this workaround, to no avail:
<vc:account-logo skin='@(theme.BaseSettings.Layout.DarkMode ? "dark.png?a=x": "light.png?a=x")'></vc:account-logo>

It emits the same HTML.
Is there a better workaround?

I think this is a bug in ASPNETZero.  For the time being, I'm using this JavaScript to change the & into a ?
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").each(function () {
        const src = $(this).attr("src");
        const fixed = src.replace(".png&", ".png?");
        $(this).attr("src", fixed);
    });
});

